# Inserting date and time as "2021-05-13T12:31" in database?

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-migrations

I am having a `datetime` input in my form and the user will select date and time from that input. But when inserting, the data should be only date and time, but T also getting inserted? How not to insert it?
Here is the **migration** code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('competitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('desc');
        $table->float('entry_fees');
        $table->varchar('start_date_time',50);
        $table->Date('end_date_time',50);
        $table->integer('status');
        $table->string('date_time');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The columns name are `start_date_time` and `end_date_time`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just datetime can you not set your columns like this then carbon parse on creating

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('competitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('desc');
        $table->float('entry_fees');
        $table->datetime('start_date_time');
        $table->datetime('end_date_time');
        $table->integer('status');
        $table->string('date_time');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first your columns should be dateTime type in your table and then
you can change its format with laravel carbon

```
$createdAt = Carbon::parse($item['start_date_time']);
```

Then you can use

```
$start_date = $createdAt->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```